# Error text on submit

Tags: angularjs

I want to show required text when clicked on submit button.

The issue is iam not using form.

how to show *required text when the input field is submitted empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign `ng-form` attribute to parent container(`div` or `section` or any other tags)

**For Example**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('validateCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = '';
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>  
<div  ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="validateCtrl" ng-form="form1">
  <p>Username:<br>
  <input type="text" name="user" ng-model="user" required>
  <span style="color:red" ng-show="submitted && form1.user.$invalid">
    <span ng-show="form1.user.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
  </span>
  </p>

  <p>
    <input type="submit" ng-click="submitted=true">
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Really thanks for your reply @sushmit.patil, But I wanted the error message on button click.

Comment: @User123, Edited solution as per your requirement

Comment: I Got the Solution myself, but really thanks for replying @sushmit.patil. Any way Iam accepting you answer.